# Forgot Oracle username and password, how to retrieve?

Tags: oracle11g

I have forgotten my Oracle username and password and hence not able to use it. My Oracle version is 11.2.0.1.0(11g). I consulted Internet. They asked me to execute commands like ‘SYSDBA’ but I was unable to do it as once I give ‘SYSDBA’ on Command Prompt screen, it takes the command as the username and next asks for password. I cannot execute any commands suggested by them as whatever I enter is taken as the username, subsequently password is asked and error occurs.

Answer (score 36):

1. Open your SQL command line and type the following:

   ```
   SQL> connect / as sysdba
   ```
2. Once connected,you can enter the following query to get details of username and password:

   ```
   SQL> select username,password from dba_users;
   ```
3. This will list down the usernames,but passwords would not be visible.But you can identify the particular username and then change the password for that user.
   For changing the password,use the below query:

   ```
   SQL> alter user username identified by password;
   ```
4. Here username is the name of user whose password you want to change and password is the new password.

Comment: I also have same issue But when i Run SQL> connect / as sysdba i I'm getting error that invalid username and password

Comment: you need to enter as oracle user and then write sqlplus

Comment: You may need to connect with "connect /@<SID> as sysdba" where you replace <SID> with your instance name.

Answer (score 7):

Go to SQL command line:-
type:

```
sql>connect / as sysdba;
```

then type:

```
sql>desc dba_users;
```

then type:

```
sql>select username,password from dba_users;
```

If `sysdba` doesn't work then try connecting with username:scott and password: Tiger

You will be able to see all users with passwords.
Probably you might find your's.
Hope this helps

Comment: Just when I run my Oracle.exe, this 3 lines are displayed :
SQL*Plus: Release 11.2.0.1.0 Production on Thu Feb 4 20:45:14 2016
Copyright (c) 1982, 2010, Oracle.  All rights reserved.
Enter user-name:

These things are displayed in the dark screen. My Oracle screen only asks for the username and password, nothing else! When I entered sql>connect / sysdba, it showed ‘Connected to an idle instance’. But right after when I enter desc dba_users, it shows ‘Error, not logged on’. Other commands like desc dba_users also fail to work as it shows the same result:’Not logged on’.
Please do help.

Comment: Not able to see passwords, it only list all users present in dba_users

Answer (score 7):

1. Open Command Prompt/Terminal and type:

   > sqlplus / as SYSDBA
2. SQL prompt will turn up. Now type:

   > ALTER USER *existing_account_name* IDENTIFIED BY *new_password* ACCOUNT UNLOCK;
3. Voila! You've unlocked your account.

Answer (score 2):

The usernames are shown in the dba_users's `username` column, there is a script you can run called:

```
alter user username identified by password
```

You can get more information here - https://community.oracle.com/thread/632617?tstart=0

Comment: Just when I run my Oracle.exe, this 3 lines are displayed :
SQL*Plus: Release 11.2.0.1.0 Production on Thu Feb 4 20:45:14 2016
Copyright (c) 1982, 2010, Oracle.  All rights reserved.
Enter user-name:

These things are displayed in the dark screen. My Oracle screen only asks for the username and password, nothing else! When I entered sql>connect / sysdba, it showed ‘Connected to an idle instance’. But right after when I enter desc dba_users, it shows ‘Error, not logged on’. Other commands like desc dba_users also fail to work as it shows the same result:’Not logged on’.
Please do help.

Answer (score 2):

if you are on Windows

1. Start the Oracle service if it is not started (most probably it starts automatically when Windows starts)
2. Start CMD.exe
3. in the cmd (black window) type:
   `sqlplus / as sysdba`

Now you are logged with SYS user and you can do anything you want (query DBA_USERS to find out your username, or change any user password). You can not see the old password, you can only change it.

Comment: when i write the sqlplus / as sysdba , it again prompts for username and password. How can i fix it?

Comment: Looks like your Oracle instance starts with different OS account. Try to start CMD with that specific account (or Administrator)

Comment: This can fail with `ORA-01031: insufficient privileges`.